# Comprobar que cada elemento de un arreglo sea igual al otro. Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

estoy con una duda existencial.

Tengo una función, que debe retornar true en caso de que cada elemento de un arreglo sea igual al otro.

Tengo un arreglo con cinco elementos que cambian constantemente, y cada vez que un nuevo elemento se pushea, la función ya dicha se ejecuta y comprueba si todos los elementos son iguales.

Hasta acá todo bien. El problema es que hice un juego de condicionales (copypaste), pero es una manera horrible de escribir un código, así que recurro a estos foros para ver qué soluciones ofrecen.

Una demostración funcional similar a mi código.

```js
let contador = ["juan", "juan", "juan", "juan", "juan"]

function bantrue() {
  if (contador[0] == contador[1]) {
    if (contador[1] == contador[2]) {
      if (contador[2] == contador[3]) {
        if (contador[3] == contador[4]) {
          return true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

if (bantrue() === true){
 document.write("bantrue() es true.");
}

//PERO SI ES FALSO 

let contador2 = ["juan", "Manuel", "juan", "juan", "juan"]

function bantrue2() {
  if (contador2[0] == contador2[1]) {
    if (contador2[1] == contador2[2]) {
      if (contador2[2] == contador2[3]) {
        if (contador2[3] == contador2[4]) {
          return true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

if (bantrue2() === true){
 document.write("true");
} else {
  document.write(" ------- bantrue2() es false.");
}
```

Como pueden ver, la primer función retorna true porque el arreglo tiene todo "juan", pero el segundo arreglo tiene un "manuel", así que los condicionales se detienen.

¿qué tal si yo quiero aumentar la cantidad de elementos que almacena *contador[]*? ¿tengo que copiar y pegar lo ifs cinco veces más? 
No lo veo práctico.

Agradecería mucho otras soluciones para realizar esta comprobación.
Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo necesario seria aplicar un ciclo que compare el valor en posicion i con la posicion siguiente (i+1), te dejo un ejemplo usando for pero tambien sale con un while. espero que sea de ayuda

```js
let contador = ["juan", "juan", "juan", "juan", "juan"]
let Tam = contador.length;
var igual = false;
function bantrue() {
  for ( let i = 0; i < Tam-1; i++){   
    if (contador[i] == contador[i+1]) {
        igual = true
    }else{
      igual = false
      break
    }
  }
  return igual
}

if (bantrue() === true){
 document.write("bantrue() es true.");
}else{
  document.write("bantrue() es false.");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me funcionó a la perfección. Si los dos primeros elementos entrantes al arreglo son iguales, lamentablemente retorna True, pero a partir de ese no devuelve True hasta que todos los elementos sean iguales. 
Una solución es forzar que los dos primeros elementos entrantes sean diferentes para que la función no retorne True hasta que todos los elementos sean iguales.

Comment: Igual a ti por comentar. No entendi lo otro muy bien.

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente puedes usar la función [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), comparando el primer elemento contra el resto.

```
array.every( a=> array[0] === a)
```

Ejemplo

```js
let contador = ["juan", "juan", "juan", "juan", "juan"]
let contador2 = ["juan", "Manuel", "juan", "juan", "juan"]

function bantrue(array) {
  return array.every( a=> array[0] === a);
}

console.log(bantrue(contador));
console.log(bantrue(contador2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Y si el dia de mañana te dan un array con un millon de posiciones? Escribirias un millon de `if's` xD ?

Yo te aconsejaria hacer la comparacion usando el ciclo `WHILE`, donde solo ciclaras mientras sigue la igualdad, ni bien encuentres una desigualdad, el ciclo se corta y el programa se termina, retornando un valor TRUE.

Por ejemplo:

```
let contador = ["juan", "juan", "juan", "juan", "juan"]
```

En este caso recorre todo el array para estar seguro que todos los valores son iguales.

```
let contador2 = ["juan", "Manuel", "juan", "juan", "juan"]
```

Y en este caso ni bien el programa ve que "juan" es distinto a "Manuel", el ciclo se cortara y no se ciclara mas.

---

El codigo quedaria mas o menos asi:

```
index = 0;
indexSiguente = 1;

while(array.length > indexSiguente-1 && array[index] == array[indexSiguente]){
 index++;
 indexSiguente++;
}
```

return (indexSiguente < array.length)

Comment: Gracias por el comentario. El arreglo es dinámico, a medida que un nuevo elemento entra, el primero se elimina. La función me retorna siempre falso :c 
Pero es muy interesante el uso de comparar números para retornar un booleano, la verdad, me fue de gran ayuda aunque no resuelva el problema. 
Gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

la forma as sencilla es

```
  let igual = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < arreglo.length-1 ; i++) {
    if (arreglo[i] !== arreglo[i + 1]) {
      igual=false;
      break;
     
    }
  }
  return igual;
```

Comment: Por favor, lee [answer]. Es necesario que expliques [qué hace el código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/).

Comment: Código sin explicación es como un hechizo de Harry Potter: funciona, nadie sabe porque ni como.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo resolvería así:

```
function todosIguales(array) {
  
    // Comparamos el primer número con todos los demás en el arreglo
    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] !== array[0]) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    // Si no se ha retornado `false` aún, todos los números son iguales
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de Bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!.